# Detect if a jQuery object is on the page or not

Tags: jquery, dom

Given a jQuery object, `$j`, I need to know if it represents something that is already on the page or if it is something that has not yet been put on the page. For example, if I have this:

```
$j = $('#id-of-something-already-on-the-page');
```

or

```
$j = $('<p>Where is pancake house?</p>').appendTo($('#this-is-already-there'));
```

Then I have something on the page and I don't need to put it on the page. But, if I just have this:

```
$j = $("<p>I'll cook you some eggs, Margie.</p>");
```

Then I'd need to append it before it is on the page.

The question is how do you ask `$j` if it is on the page or not? I know two ways the work well enough:

1. See if it has a parent: `$j.parent().length > 0` implies that it is on the page.
2. See if it has a valid index: `$j.index() > -1` implies that it is on the page.

I can see the first one failing if `$j` is the `html` or possibly `body`; I'm happy to ignore those two pathological cases. I can't think of any way that the second approach would fail.

Is there a standard technique for asking if a jQuery object is on the page or not? I don't care if `$j` is visible.

Comment: $j could have a parent and not be on the document you know ...

Comment: another possible test: `$j.closest('body').size()>0`

Comment: @drachenstern: Good point. The best part of asking a question is having someone point out the obvious issues. The same problem would, presumably, also apply to the index approach as they're checking similar things.

Comment: @Michael: That "super parent" approach could suffer the same problem as just checking `$j.parent().length` in certain pathological cases, couldn't it? OTOH, if someone is trying to put a body in a body they probably deserve a bit of suffering.

Comment: @Michael Haren: How do you feel about throwing that down as an answer? It is better than my (somewhat fragile and narrow) approaches and I can't think of anything better; I'd probably say `$j.closest('body').length > 0` but that's just a style issue. I can't see `closest('body')` failing except in bizarre pathological cases.

Comment: Oh my god, mu asked a second question! :p

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Personally, I'd start by descending from an element you know *is* in the page, like `<html>` or `<body>`, and use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
if ($('html').has($j).length)
{
    // $j is in the page
}
```

This works even for the two pathological cases you mentioned. It's [more idiomatic](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/) to check `.length` rather than `.size()`. There's also no reason to check that the value returned is `> 0`. The `length` property will *always* be a nonnegative integer, so it's sufficient to check the truthiness of the value.

Comment: There is a good reason for `> 0` and that is readability.  However, it may not be worth the extra keystrokes, especially when most javascript coders will understand the meaning without it.

Comment: I have a mild concern over the weight of this on large pages. But +1, it's sure-fire.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably just check to see if the element can reach the body element:

```
$j.closest('body').size()>0
```

As you noted in other comments, this would fail in some exceptional cases where you are handling extra body elements. If you really want to detect those situations, I guess you could check to see if you have multiple $(`body`) elements but I suspect that such extreme cases will get out of control pretty quickly.

This "is-probably-attached-to-page" check could be turned in to a [bona-fide jQuery selector](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html), too:

```
$.expr[':'].isProbablyAttached = function(obj){

    return $(obj).closest('body').size()>0;
};

// Usage:
$('.someClasses:isProbablyAttached').doSomething();
```

Comment: I've used `$.expr` before but I only need this in one place for now so I don't think I need to get that fancy. Yet.

Comment: @Michael @mu Why not `closest('html')`?

Comment: Why use `.size()>0` when you can just use `.length`? http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F

Comment: @Šime: I think looking for `'html'` would suffer the same issues as looking for `'body'` so it would, AFAIK, come down to a question of taste.

Comment: @Matt: I use `.length`, I don't think I've ever used `.size()` for anything but, again, personal preference and all that.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure that the browsers allow multiple BODY elements inside the same document. Afaik, there can only be one BODY element per document. From my experience, if you define multiple BODY elements in the source code, the browsers will ignore the additional BODY tags and only display the text content of those elements.

Comment: Sorry Michael but Matt Ball's is the tightest solution so I have to change my mind here.

Comment: No worries--his solution is better (+1)

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery (at least with version 1.7.1) `$('html').parent()` returns a non-empty array (`[#document]`):

```
$j = $("<p>I'll cook you some eggs, Margie.</p>");
$j.parent().length === 0
$('html').parent().length === 1
$('body').parent().length === 1
```

So 'mu is too short''s note is not an issue:

> I can see the first one failing if $j is the html or possibly body; I'm happy to ignore those two pathological cases. I can't think of any way that the second approach would fail.

Answer (score -2):

The jQuery object represents a collection of html elements.

After your selection: $j = $('#id-of-something-already-on-the-page');

All you have to do is check $j.length.  If it's one, there is one item on the page.

Comment: Not true. If I detach the node and store it in a variable, it still exists as a variable. If I later test that variable to see if some code re-inserted it into the DOM (think: passing a reference instead of refiltering for it everytime, and branching statements to do various actions like detach or wrap) then it may or may not be in the DOM. You can't always know what the id is going to be, if you're writing a function where you pass in a reference to a node. Also: context querying.

Comment: Or if I have `$j = $("<p>I'll cook you some eggs, Margie.</p>")` then `$j.length == 1` but the paragraph isn't on the page until I `$('body').append($j)` (or something similar) to insert it into the DOM.